# How to consistently ignore one byte from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I am dealing with a program that consistently returns many `byte` objects.

Frequently it returns the null `b'00'` in the middle of strings.  I want to  completely ignore that, (say if I were to make an array of these bytes). Is the only way to include a:

```
if bytes != b'\x00':
# Do something
```

in every single loop / part of my code or is there a better way for me to skip those bytes?

**Bonus Question**: When referring to situations such as this in Python 3, is a long "string" of bytes a "byte object", "string of bytes" or "byte array"?

What is the proper terminology?

Comment: `b'00'` is **two** bytes; each with integer value 48 (ASCII charaters `'0'`). Did you mean `b'\x00'` perhaps?

Comment: You could filter out the bytes after reading the data, instead of doing it at the time of reading.

Comment: Don't call them arrays, python has an [array](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html) class built in that does not share the same interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"? Do you want to remove them from the data or something?

Comment: Basically skip them (or treat them if they were not there at all). For example if there were bytes object and the hex value `\x80' appeared several times, how could I skip over it and continue processing the bytes  object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'd use a filtered version of the object, for example:

```
In [63]: test
Out[63]: 'hello\x00world'
In [68]: for my_bytes in filter(lambda x: x != b'\x00', test):
   ....:     print(my_bytes)
   ....:
h
e
l
l
o
w
o
r
l
d
```

Note I used `my_bytes` instead of `bytes`, which is a built-in name you'd rather not overwrite.

Similar you can also simply construct a filtered bytes object for further processing:

```
In [62]: test = b'hello\x00world'
In [63]: test
Out[63]: 'hello\x00world'
In [64]: test_without_nulls = bytes(filter(lambda x: x != b'\x00', test))
In [65]: test_without_nulls
Out[65]: 'helloworld'
```

I usually use `bytes` objects as it does not share the interface with strings in python 3. Certainly not byte [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/array.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on filtering.  However, I have never seen Python syntax with the `IN` and `OUT[]`? This does look like a great way to do it.

Comment: @Startec you can ignore that, it's console input/output from ipython that I pasted here (similar to >>> used in regular python shell), it's not part of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a membership test using `in`:

```
>>> b'\x00' in bytes([1, 2, 3])
False
>>> b'\x00' in bytes([0, 1, 2, 3])
True
```

Here `b'\x00'` produces a `bytes` object with a single NULL byte (as opposed to `b'00'` which produces an object of length 2 with two bytes with integer values 48).

I call these things `bytes` objects, sometimes byte strings, but the latter usually in context of Python 2 only. A `bytearray` is a separate, distinct type (a mutable version of the `bytes` type).

Comment: Could you please look at this question? It explains my problem better and I think addresses your comment above.  Thank you for this helpful answer as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480639/issues-with-bytes-from-a-microcontroller-in-python

Comment: @KillianDS  The reason I asked a separate question was that to me it seemed different enough to warrant doing so.  This question is much more specific to one case (ignoring a repeatedly appearing byte value), while the other addresses how to deal with a `bytes` object containing `null` values that can be received in one or several messages. If you do not agree I am more than happy to change this question, however, the answers here would not fit. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list in python, you can do

```
list = [x for x in originallist if x is not None]
```

Comment: Replace none with the values and if you have multiple values to ignore, use the and statement