# Issues with Bytes from a Microcontroller in Python

Tags: python, byte

I am using Python to read micro controller values in a windows based program. The encodings / byte decodings and values have begun to confuse me.  Here is my situation:

In the software, I am allowed to call a `receive` function once per `byte` received by the Python interpreter, once per `line` (not quite sure what that is) or once per `message` which I assume is the entire transmission from the micro controller.

I am struggling with the best way to decode these values.  The microcontroller is putting out specific values that correlate to a protocol.  For example, calling a function that is supposed to return the `hex` values:

```
F0, 79, (the phrase standard_firmata.pde) [then] F7
```

returns:

```
b'\xf0y\x02\x03S\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00a\x00r\x00d\x00F\x00i\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00o\x00\xf7'
```

When set to "once per message" .  This is what I want, I can see that the correct values are being sent, but there are too man `\x00` values included (they are after every byte it seems).  Additionally, the second `byte` is `0y`when it is supposed to be `79`. It seems like it printed its value in `ASCII` when all the others were in hex.

How can I ignore all these `null` characters and make everything in the right format (I am fine with normal hex values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consistently ignore one byte from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480433/how-to-consistently-ignore-one-byte-from-a-string); this question should be an edit to that one.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I think we can treat them as two separate posts; the other is a X-Y problem post more.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I am happy to merge them, however, the answers to each have helped me with two different problems (i.e. questions) so I think it makes sense to keep them separate.

Comment: Okay; fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python represents a `bytes` value, it'll use the ASCII representation for anything that has a printable character. Thus the hex 0x79 byte is indeed represented by a `y`:

```
>>> b'\x79'
b'y'
```

Using ASCII characters makes the representation more readable, but doesn't affect the contents. You can use `\x..` hex and ASCII notations interchangeably when creating `bytes` values.

The data appears to encode a [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) message, little endian:

```
>>> data = b'\xf0y\x02\x03S\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00a\x00r\x00d\x00F\x00i\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00o\x00\xf7'
>>> data[4:-1].decode('utf-16-le')
'̂StandardFirmata.ino'
```

UTF 16 uses 2 bytes per character, and for ASCII (and Latin 1) codepoints that means that each 2nd byte is a null.

You can use simple comparisons to test for message types:

```
if data[:2] == b'\xf0\x79':
    assert data[-1] == 0xf7, "Message did not end with F7 closing byte"
    version = tuple(data[2:4])
    message = data[4:-1].decode('utf-16-le')
```

Comment: I should have explained.  The `\x02` and `\x03` refer to the a firmware version running on the microcontroller.  This is part of my confusion.  An ascii representation is used for the characters, but not those values (which correspond to Major Version 2, Minor Version 3)

Comment: @Startec: right, converted those directly to integers for you then.

Comment: I see this.  It is a wonderful help, out of more than curiosity, how did you find it would be `utf-16-le`?

Comment: @Startec: I recognised the typical UTF-16 pattern (null bytes in between) and then there are only two options; little endian and big endian. Since there is no BOM I had to pick one explicitly.

Comment: @Startec: your microcontroller documentation probably mentions the encoding explicitly.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the documentation makes no mention of the encoding. However, Thank you for all your help.

Comment: One more item: It seems that just the `slicing` of bytes changes them from hex to binary but I can't see where this is documented. Is this standard behavior?

I would love to slice this into an array of integers but `data = bytes[:]` does not seem to do it.

Comment: @Startec: no such thing happens. Slicing produces a new `bytes` object with the same value. Did you mean 'produces integers'? You can address individual byte values with indexing (`data[-1] == 0xF7` did that, it got the last byte and compared to another integer).

Comment: @Startec: converting a bytes object to tuple or list pulls out a sequence of integers.

Comment: This is so bizarre: From your above example:
 `if data[0] == b'\xf0':
  print('yes') #Doesn't print yes`
but
     `if data[:1] == b'\xf0':
  print('yes') #Prints yes`

Aren't they the same?

Comment: @Startec: no, one is indexing, the other is slicing. Indexing gives you integers, slicing another `bytes` object.

Comment: Oh...I see, from your comments above, [:1] would convert it to a list (making it an integer) whereas [0] references a position? Yep...just saw your comment.

Comment: @Startec: `[:1]` doesn't convert it to a list, it produces a `bytes` object containing the sliced bytes.

Comment: @Martin, Thank you for this great answer (to which I still refer).  However, I do have an unexpected follow-up: If I do `data[4:-4].decode('utf-16-le')` (from the above example) I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x6e in position 34: truncated data` Do you know why this is? Do I have to decode the `bytes` object then `slice` the string?

Comment: @Startec: you cut off to much or to little from the end. `data[4:-3]` or `data[4:-5]` should work.

Comment: @Startec: Each UTF-16 character takes *two* bytes and you are trying to decode an odd number of bytes. You need an even number instead.

Comment: It happened that I specifically want to cutoff that part of the string (a filename extension). Is it unavoidable? Does Python/Unicode have some sort of rules for where and when it can stop decoding?

Comment: @Startec: For UTF-16, you need even bytes; each character is always 2 bytes. It'll be easier to ignore the filename extension **after** decoding, with `os.path.splitext()`.

Comment: how long have you used Python, you are *by far* the most helpful person on SO when it comes to Python

Comment: @Startec: 15 years and counting.

Comment: I guess that'll do it.

Comment: To me this is an example of a perfect SO answer. Explained why I was confused, and offered a great solution.